# using this.props.someVariable

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs, react-native

I am using this.props.someVariable to pass on a variable from one component to another. I would like to debug the variable using console.log().

I am not able to use it in console.log(this.props.someVariable) but it works fine within a tag.

```
var secondComp = React.createClass({
  render(){
    console.log({this.props.myProp}); // doesn't work
    return(
        <Text>{this.props.myProp}</Text>
          );   
  } 
});
```

Comment: call `log` method like: `console.log(this.props.myProp);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do:

```
console.log(this.props.myProp);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a JavaScript expression as an attribute value, wrap the expression in a pair of curly braces ({}) and To render a React Component, just create a local variable or pass it.

[this.props — spread attributes to ensure any props passed down are available as usual as this.props]

```
var secondComp = React.createClass({
render(){
// or can store it in some variable
var a = this.props.myProp;
console.log(a); 
console.log(this.props.myProp);// you don't need curly braces 
return(
    <Text>{this.props.myProp}</Text>
      );   
} 
});
```

Comment: It's always better to add an explanation to the code you're posting as an answer, so that it will helps visitors understand why this is a good answer.

Comment: added some Thanks!